# Trying to add ImageTexture to a shape of IndexedFaceSet, how can I control the appearance of ImageTexture?

Tags: webots

I tried to build a cup like can.proto, but the appearance of ImageTexture was strange. How can I control it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by strange? The mapping is not the one you are expecting?
Can you maybe add an image of the result and of what you would expect?

Comment: In the can.proto, the ImageTexture on the side of cylinder is continuous. But for our model imported from Solidworks, the ImageTexture on the side of cylinder has a symmetry plane.  See the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC8pQ.png;  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiuJM.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems the texture mapping of your IndexedFaceSet (https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/indexedfaceset) node is not defined (or wrongly defined). You can define it using the 'texCoord' field of the IndexedFaceSet node.

The texture mapping defines how each point of the IndexedFaceSet is mapped to the texture. I would recommend reading this: https://www.rigacci.org/docs/biblio/online/vrml/ch15.htm